# How to mock CanCan's "authorize!" method in a controller spec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, rspec, cancan

The simplest way to write specs checking that a controller is authorizing the signed-in current_user to use the said action is to explicitly write two specs checking that a user with permission can run that action, and another cannot. For example:

```
 # The controller action:

 def some_action
   authorize! :do_this_action, @some_object
 end

 # The spec:

 it "should work when authorized" do
   sign_in @user
   get :some_action
   response.should be_success
 end

 it "should not work when not authorized" do
   sign_in @other_user
   get :some_action
   response.should_not be_success
 end
```

But this is not great, as it requires a great amount of code (two or more specs) and doesn't actually test directly that the authorization is being checked (`do_this_action` in the example).

I would like to be able to write a simpler spec, e.g. (an example using 'rr' for mocking)

```
 it "should check the user can do_this_action" do
   mock(controller).authorize!(:do_this_action, some_object)
   get :some_action
 end
```

I think this would be shorter and directly test that the authorization check I want to be used is being run. But, I can't figure out how to write the mock. `mock(controller)` isn't correct, nor does mocking `ApplicationController` or `Ability` seem to work.

How do I write this kind of mock?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the way I was writing above works.. must have had a typo earlier.

So, to check that an authorize! check is invoked in the controller, you just need to write:

```
 it "should check the user can do_this_action" do
   mock(controller).authorize!(:some_action, some_object)
   get :some_action
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it would be better to test authorization in another spec like ability_spec.rb in order for you to separate their responsibilities. By doing so you won't have to test the same authorization method that you use on different controllers.

heres some other [details](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Testing-Abilities)

Comment: yeah, that is what i'm trying to refactor toward. I want to just check that the correct authorize! check is invoked in the controller, and have strict tests for the actual authorization logic solely in ability_spec.rb.